# Beam with internal hinge - Reactions help

Tags: structural-analysis

can someone explain why the highlighted area (at Mb=0) is **-** 5x2 and not positive? Since the rest of the loads(and the rest of that very same load) pointing down were documented with a +, 
I dont understand why this part is calculated with a minus.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AV4r.png): [image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because by convention they have set clockwise moment as positive. We are taking moments so we consider the sign of the direction of the rotation not the load.

Inspecting line you have highlighted: the sum of moments about B, we see they have assigned negative to the reaction C (-7.c) implying counterclockwise as negative.

So with this convention, the moment 5*2*1 should be negative because it is counterclockwise.

It would not make any difference in the final reactions, it's just that usually we assume the counterclockwise moments as positive.